# How to align rows from two different files by similitude?

Tags: bash, unix

I need help to align two files by similitude of the values from the column 2 (file 1) and column 1 (file 2).

file 1:

```
1 d 3
2 e 4 
5 o 1
```

file 2:

```
e 6
o 5
d 8
```

I want to get

```
1 d 3 d 8
2 e 4 e 6
5 o 1 o 5
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `join` command?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) command:

```
join -o "1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2" -1 2 <(cat file1 | sort) <(cat file2 | sort)
```

output:

```
1 d 3 d 8
2 e 4 e 6
5 o 1 o 5
```

Your files will need to be sorted for this to work. They weren't, so I had to sort them for you.

Answer (score 0):

If both files have exactly the same keys (and number of lines), you can use `paste`:

```
paste -d\  <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort file2)
```